# Finite Rings have Invariant Dimension Property

Tags: abstract-algebra

I need help this question

> Prove that every finite ring has the Invariant Dimension Property (IDP). (Assume $1_R \neq 0_R$.)

This is what I know I should do.  Let $X$ and $Y$ be two sets such that the free module with basis $X$ is isomorphic to the free module with basis $Y$. Next, I have to show that $|X| = |Y|$. This is where I'm stuck.

Thanks.

Comment: Using cardinal arithmetic, under certain axioms of set theory, you can show that if $R$ is a finite set, then $|R^X|=|R^Y|$ implies that $|X|=|Y|$.  This is elementary if $X$ and $Y$ are finite, but interesting things can happen otherwise, as seen at http://mathoverflow.net/questions/17152/when-2a-2b-implies-ab-a-b-cardinals.  Of course, an isomorphism is more than just a bijection, and I believe that the answer to your question does not depend on the result mentioned above.  Isomorphism of infinite rank free-modules always implies equality of the rank.

Comment: Maybe there is a more elementary proof for the case when $R$ is finite, but a reference is Hungerford's *Algebra*, Theorem IV.2.6 for the general case of infinite rank free modules over unital rings.

Answer (score 2):

Just count the number of elements. Since $R$ is finite, you can say exactly how many elements a free modulo of rank $k$ has. For finite $k$, that will do it. In the infinite case, you'll need to do a bit of cardinal work.

Answer (score 1):

As $R$ is finite, it is Artinian, so the modules $R^m$ and $R^n$
have finite length. You can now use the Jordan-Hölder theorem
to deduce that $R^m\cong R^n$ implies $m=n$.

Or you can just count :-)